# :active pseudo-class - making a keypress act like a mouse click with respect to :active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### :active pseudo-class w/keypress event.

---

I have svg buttons I drew for a drum machine I'm working on.  I use a css :active to change their x: and y: when :active with 'click tap' event, they also play a sound.  i have bound them to keyboard as well.  i can't figure out if i can add active pseudo class somehow so keypress acts like mouse click.

---

I researched and didn't find much.  what I did come across was vague and not exactly what I am trying.  I'm using jquery.  I did come up with another solution which is a addClass tied to a keyframes with a setTimeout that does get the effect I want.  I just want to know if there is a more efficient way to control :active.

---

[My Codepen](http://codepen.io/benjaminadk/pen/oWaBqy?editors=0010)

---

I would want to simply add active instead of doing separate animation for 20 buttons. My code works it just seems like their would be an easier way, and I would like to know it.

---

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
switch(e.which) {
    case 40:bass.play();
            screen.text("bass drum");
            $("#btnright").addClass("test");
            setTimeout(function()                                                       
  {$("#btnright").removeClass("test");},200);
    break;

    case 32 :snare.play();
            screen.text("snare drum"); 
    break;

    case 39: high
```

And some of the CSS

---

```
    #btnright:active{
  x:-304;
  y:-468;
}
.test{
  animation: test .2s linear; 
}
@keyframes test{
  0%{}
  50%{x:-304; y:-468;}
  100%{}
}
```

---

To see the effect I want use the down arrow.  I should also say sorry if this is an ignorant question.  I am a total noob saibot.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to modify pseudo-classes using JavaScript so you'll need to toggle an `active` class.

Example

JS

```
var $btn = $('#btn')
$(document)
.keydown(event => {
    $btn.addClass('active')
})
.keyup(event => {
    $btn.removeClass('active')
})
```

CSS

```
#btn:active,
#btn.active {
 ...
}
```

**[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbVzyO)**

Resources:

- [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin/5041526#5041526)